# Repetitive match in Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

In this string, I want to extract 4 sub-strings:

```
group(1) = F
group(2) = abcg
group(3) = abc
group(4) = abde

String str = "F abcgXabcXabde";    
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(F\\s)(.+)X(.+)X(.+)")
```

This pattern looks fine. However, how to write the pattern if the number of the X-delimited substring is unknown?

Comment: Can't you just split instead of using Regex?

Comment: If split, the first element in the result(i.e. result[0]) would be "F"?

Comment: just split by space and X and it would be `split[0]`

Comment: How to write this split pattern? str.split("F\\sX")? It doesn't work.

Comment: `str.split("\\s|X");` - Splits by space and `X`: See [here](http://ideone.com/Rs7hza)